# Deserializing XML containing list into a POJO

Tags: java, xml, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

My XML looks something like this:

```
<asset  id="35465146">
    <TOV artist="" music="0" episodeNumber="">
        <credit biography="" />
        <credit biography="" />
        <credit biography="" />
        <credit biography="" />
        <castCrew role="Actor" name="John C. Reilly"/>
        <castCrew role="Director" name="Keith Scholey"/>
        <castCrew role="Director" name="Alastair Fothergill"/>
        <castCrew role="Director" name="Adam Chapman"/>
    </TOV>
</asset>
```

My asset POJO looks like this:

```
public class asset {
    @Getter @Setter private String id;
    @Getter @Setter private TOV TOV;
}
```

and the TOV class look like this:

```
public class TOV {
    @Getter @Setter private String episodeNumber;
    @Getter @Setter private String music;
    @Getter @Setter private String artist;
    @Getter @Setter private List<credit> credit;
    @Getter @Setter private List<castCrew> castCrew;

}
```

Now, I run the code and get a null pointer.
When I debug the code I see that the asset object has been created and that the ID field has been extracted from the XML. However, the TOV object is equal to null. Do I require some sort of label to tell Jackson that the TOV java object maps to the XML one? Also, would having credit and castCrew inside a java List work?

Comment: If your XML looks like that, it is malformed. Episode number has an extra quote.

Comment: its not like that, its much bigger, i shortened it and left it in by accident

Answer (score 0):

In the asset class I was missing

```
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "TOV")
```

On top of

```
@Getter @Setter private TOV TOV;
```

And for the list I needed to add

```
@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "castCrew")
```

Both problems were just related to having to specify which field in java it should be mapped to in the XML